# converting to byte[] and String.getBytes

Tags: java

As part of an exercise I had to write a remote class loader. It downloads a class from a server and then loads it using defineClass.

What I did was something like this:

```
in=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
Object o = in.readObject();
return defineClass(className,o.toString().getBytes(), 0, o.toString().length());
```

And I got a `java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value`

But when I wrote this

```
in=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
byte[] classData=(byte[])in.readObject();
return defineClass(className,classData, 0, classData.length);
```

It worked as expected.

Why is that?

Comment: `toString` doesn't encode the bytes of the object - it returns a string that contains information about the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.toString()` string returns you `human readable form of Object` So if you call `toString` on `array` object then it will return you `default toString`.

Default toString implementation is

```
public String toString() {
return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

You can clearly see this is not what you wanted.

You can use [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) constructor with `Charset` or default charset to convert `byte[]`to string

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
```

---

References:

- [Byte Encodings and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)
- [String JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Answer (score 0):

my interpretation is that happens because an `objectinputstream` in java is kind of an `byteinputstream`. Therefore u can use the 2nd solution. the first wouldn't work because of the `toString()` implementation of Object.